# Calling someone a “blank” professor

Tags: single-word-requests

I think there’s a term for someone who is brilliant in one area but dumb/disorganized when it comes to everyone else. It’s some word plus  professor. Like “messy professor” or something like that. Can anyone think of what I mean?

Answer (score 3):

You're probably thinking of "The Absent-Minded Professor," a term popularized by a [Disney film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Absent-Minded_Professor) from 1961.  It's a stock character at this point with roots in mythology ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absent-minded_professor)):

> The phrase "absent-minded professor" is also commonly used more
> generally in English to describe people who are so engrossed in their
> "own world" that they fail to keep track of their surroundings. It is
> a common stereotype that professors get so obsessed with their
> research that they pay little attention to anything else.

"The Nutty Professor" is more of a Jekyll and Hyde character, though that is a common a reference as well, also from a film in the 60s that was remade in the 90s.  Not as good a fit for your description, but the two get confused.